# Subversion (SVN) - updating local directory with large files

Tags: svn

I want to manage version control over large files (over 1 GB), for a large number of users. They are all working on the same shared environment, and we can't afford each one of them "svn updating" these large files as their local copies.
EDIT: The users are required to work with these large files, often.

Can anyone advise:
1. What is the best practice to handle such problems?
2. Is there a way for the users to "svn update" only a link to the big file that is in the repository?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure it completely addresses your problem, but they can do selective checkouts. In other words, can they checkout a portion of the repository (i.e., a subdirectory) which excludes these big files you're concerned about?

Comment: SVN is not really ment for handling such large files. Can't you put the files on a fileshare instead?

Comment: ScoPi - I am aware of selective checkouts, but the users are required to work with these large files.

Comment: Albin - A fileshare does not have the features of version control, such as remembering file history and being able to pull older versions.

Comment: What do you mean shared environment? Everybody will be logged on to a server and work with the files locally there? If you are going to modify the files, how are you going to ensure they don't overwrite each other's changes?

Comment: You can't create a link to a file in different environment. Which makes it even less clear how you want your setup to look.

Comment: Jan - Yes they are logged on to the same server. I AM going to modify those big files, SVN takes care of the versions each user uses, ensuring each user works with his own copy. My question is how to work with SVN in a way the users don't have to pull the whole file into their working copies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the subversion repository you mention is named repoA, and these large files are stored in one directory, path is `repoA/dirA`.

Since the users are not allowed to change these large files, it it logical to move these files into different repo, say `repoB/dirA`.

Then you can checkout `repoB/dirA` into your *shared environment*, say `/path/to/repoB/dirA`.

In repoA, just delete `repoA/dirA` and replace it with a symlink to path `/path/to/repoB/dirA` (or use relative path if you wish).

Since all users will checkout the own copy of `repoA/dirA` in the same machine, the symlink will be valid.